# Why Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb failed to install?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I started with an empty solution with Web API only. (no mvc)

Using NuGet to upgrade all the built-in packages to the latest stable.

Then,

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
```

Everything's good. I get a version 5.2.2 of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin`.

After that, install `Owin.Host.SystemWeb`.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

It shows a **Successfully installed...** message. But when I look into the References of the project, the icon before **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb** has a yellow triangle in its bottom.

Here is my `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The solution can be built but with a Warning, not even an error:

> The referenced component 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb' could not be found.

The question: what is the correct way to install **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**? Is there some version requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

to

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```